# How to write query for the cumulative salary for each employee within each year

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum

[image: Query should return this output with cum sal]

This table has columns employee, month, year and salary.
I need to write sql query for this.
It should reset when we reach to December and restart calculating running sal for next year for the same employee.

As per now I am manage to write below Query but it is not enough:

```
SELECT Employee, Month, Year, Salary, SUM(Salary)  OVER(ORDER BY rownum) AS "CUM SALARY"
FROM emp
group by Employee, Month, Year, Salary,rownum;
```

Comment: Please tag the database that you are using and also let me know which is the date column in your table by which we can do ordering of the row.

Comment: Its SQL database. Query for table creation : 
CREATE TABLE emp (
 Employee varchar(255),
    Month varchar(255),
    Year int,
    Salary int
);

Comment: Insert Queries:                                                                                                       
INSERT INTO emp VALUES('A','Jan','2016','2000');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES('A','Feb','2016','2000');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES('A','Mar','2016','2000');                                                                Something like these.

Comment: Then how will we do ordering? It is bad practice to store the month name.

Comment: Yes I know. But it was interview question and I am trying to solve it now.

Comment: "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database". [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which database you are using, but this will work in Oracle database

```sql
SELECT Employee, Month, Year, Salary, SUM(Salary)  OVER(partition by Employee, Year ORDER BY to_date(Year||Month, 'YYYYMon', 'nls_date_language = english')) AS "CUM SALARY"
FROM emp
;
```

Comment: Glad to see I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sum analytical function as follows:

```
select t.*,
       sum(salary) over (partition by empployee, year 
                          order by case month when 'Jan' then 1
                                              when 'Feb' then 2
                                              .....
                                              when 'Dec' then 12
                                   end) as cum_sal
  from employee t
```

Or you can use `try_cast` as follows:

```
select t.*,
       sum(salary) over (partition by empployee, year 
                          order by TRY_CAST (concat(month,' ', year)) as cum_sal
  from employee t
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sample Query

```
WITH CTE
AS(
SELECT 
    EmpName,
    Sal_Date,  
    Salary, 
    (ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY YEAR(Sal_Date) order by EmpName,Sal_Date asc) ) ROWNO      
FROM tbl_EmpTB
GROUP BY EmpName,Sal_Date, Salary
)

SELECT EmpName,Datename(MONTH,sal_date) [Month],YEAR(sal_date) [YEAR],Salary,--CUMSAL,
SUM (Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(Sal_Date) order by EmpName,Sal_Date asc) [CUM SALARY]
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Sal_Date
```